# Working for a Mechallel Shabbos Company

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work

What are the possible halachic issues with working for a company owned by Jews that are mechallel shabbos through the company?

Assuming one does no actual work for them on Shabbos, but the work one does during the week might help them do melachos over shabbos.

For example, Lighting Design for a mechallel shabbos performing group. I do not work on Shabbos but my paperwork and work helps whoever does work on shabbos violate it.

Comment: Are the people who work on shabbos Jewish?

Comment: Yes, that's  the problem.

Comment: @Daniel Why does your premise change any circumstances are consequences, if it has no affect on your working during the week?

Comment: I don't see a problem with this at all. There are numerous restaurants in the NYC area that are Jewishly owned and these places are open on Shabbat. If I worked, there, I can cook food that I know will be sold and heated on Shabbat (by "heated" I mean in a way that is unquestionably *chillul Shabbat*.)